# Flex 4.7 Process bar

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.7

I am starting now with Flex 4.7. I know I am a bit late. Anyway, I just want to ask an experts opinion on what would be the best implementation for a process bar. Not a progress bar, a process bar. Basically its a component on the bottom of the app that tells the user which steps to go through to get to a final result. This is very common on payment methods. You have the item description -> billing info -> shippment info -> overview. Hope you guys understand...

First I was thinking, I am going to use a graph component. But then after a while, I though I simplify and create a VGroup components where I add buttons. Each button is a step. Anyway, hope this is not to much of a basic question. I just want to hear the opinion from a Flex 4.7 expert. Any example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked best for me was s:TabbedViewNavigator with a custom TabBar Skin. Using a scroller. [Flex 4.6 TabbedViewNavigator - TabBar with indication of more items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939794/flex-4-6-tabbedviewnavigator-tabbar-with-indication-of-more-items)

That lead to the question how do I indicate more items on the side. I am working on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [LinkBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d92.html) with a > or » appended to each of its labels.